# Search other items based on Taxonomy term

Tags: orchardcms

I created a few terms using Taxonomy Module. I added a Taxonomy field in my custom content type. 
Now, on the page, I want to display other items that have been tagged with the same Taxonomy term, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the term name, you can use the following query -

```
var _taxonomyService = WorkContext.Resolve<ITaxonomyService>();

var termContentItems = _taxonomyService.GetContentItems(termname)
                       .Where(c => c.ContentItem.ContentType == "YourContentTypeName")
                       .ToList();
```